# can't access class instance variable in class methods in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
class Admin{
        constructer(_name,_department,_post,_workExperience){
        this.name=_name;
        this.department=_department;
        this.post=_post;
        this.workExperience=_workExperience;
    }
    get mainJobs () {
        return ['networking','fullStack','database','itSecurity'];
        
    }
    companyCar(){
        return this.workExperience;
    }


}


let a=new Admin('ram','fullStack','admin','10');

console.log(a.companyCar());
```

**cannot access class instance variable in class method
its showing undefined
**
**cannot access class instance variable in class method
its showing undefined
**
**cannot access class instance variable in class method
its showing undefined
**

Comment: `constructor` not `constructer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was just a typo in `constructor`.

```js
class Admin {
  constructor(_name, _department, _post, _workExperience) {
    this.name = _name;
    this.department = _department;
    this.post = _post;
    this.workExperience = _workExperience;
  }

  get mainJobs() {
    return ['networking', 'fullStack', 'database', 'itSecurity'];
  }

  companyCar() {
    return this.workExperience;
  }
}


let a = new Admin('ram', 'fullStack', 'admin', '10');

console.log(a.companyCar());
```